# Convert database to utf8

Tags: mysql, utf-8, converters

Hello I'm trying to convert my database, one table and field to utf using this script

```
-- Write a script that converts hbtn_0c_0 database to UTF8
-- (utf8mb4, collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci) in your MySQL server.

-- You need to convert all of the following to UTF8:

--     Database hbtn_0c_0
--     Table first_table
--     Field name in first_table

ALTER DATABASE
      `hbtn_0c_0`
      CHARACTER SET utf8mb4
      COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

USE `hbtn_0c_0`;

ALTER TABLE
      `first_table`
      CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4
      COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

ALTER TABLE
      `first_table`
      CHANGE `name`
      VARCHAR(256)
      CHARACTER SET utf8mb4
      COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

But I have a SQL error. Please help me

```
black_genius@genius:~/Documents/ALX_Task/alx-higher_level_programming/0x0D-SQL_introduction$ cat 100-move_to_utf8.sql | mysql -hlocalhost -uroot -p 
Enter password: 
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 22: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VARCHAR(256)
      CHARACTER SET utf8mb4
      COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci' at line 4
```

I'm using mysql version v8.0.31 on ubuntu 22.10

Comment: What charset is in use now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you change a column, you need to provide the old name and the new name, even if the name is the same. See the syntax in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html):

```
CHANGE [COLUMN] old_col_name new_col_name column_definition
```

In your case it should be

```
ALTER TABLE
      `first_table`
      CHANGE `name` `name`
      VARCHAR(256)
      CHARACTER SET utf8mb4
      COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Demonstration:  . db-fiddle.com/f/qFuvFqP5PEGbsc8F8DfiaN/0

Comment: @RickJames How so? If data was not utf8, it will be converted. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qFuvFqP5PEGbsc8F8DfiaN/0

Comment: @RickJames The fiddle-demo that I posted in a comment above doesn't agree with you. Neither does the documentation: *"For data type changes using CHANGE or MODIFY, MySQL tries to convert existing column values to the new type as well as possible."*

Comment: Your are right.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to change the individual column if you use `ALTER TABLE ... CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET ...`. That ALTER TABLE automatically converts all string-based columns.

The documentation describes:

> To change the table default character set and all character columns
> (CHAR, VARCHAR, TEXT) to a new character set, use a statement like
> this:
>
> ```
> ALTER TABLE tbl_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET charset_name;
> ```
>
> The statement also changes the collation of all character columns.

Paul Spiegel's answer about the CHANGE COLUMN syntax is correct; that syntax allows you to change a column's name, so you need to specify the column name twice.

An alternative is to use `MODIFY COLUMN` instead of `CHANGE COLUMN`. This allows you to change the column type and options, including character set, but not to change the column name. So there's no need to include the column name twice.

```
ALTER TABLE
      `first_table`
      MODIFY `name`
      VARCHAR(256)
      CHARACTER SET utf8mb4
      COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

But again, in your example, there's no need to use either `CHANGE COLUMN` or `MODIFY COLUMN`. The character set conversion should be achieved by using the `CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET` action.

Answer (score 0):

***ALTER DATABASE hbtn_0c_0 CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
USE hbtn_0c_0;***
--The above command will converts hbtn_0c_0 database to UTF8 and selects hbtn_0c_0 databas
-- convert first_table to UTF8
***ALTER TABLE first_table
CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;***
---the above one converts your table to utf-8

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).